# Parsing html code with html error problem

Tags: php, html-parsing

I want to parse the link: http://dizli.com/dizli/db.html using php.

But when i wrote the code,

```
$url = "http://dizli.com/dizli/db.html";
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html = $dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
$tr = $tables->item(2)->getElementsByTagName('tr');
$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('td');

foreach($rows as $row)
{
    $movie = $row->getElementsByTagName('b');
    echo $movie;}
```

I got bunch of errors:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile() [domdocument.loadhtmlfile]: Opening and ending tag mismatch: font and td in http://dizli.com/dizli/db.html, line: 54 in C:\development\app_server\C7\Lib\Tools\News.php on line 93

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile() [domdocument.loadhtmlfile]: Opening and ending tag mismatch: font and b in http://dizli.com/dizli/db.html, line: 81 in C:\development\app_server\C7\Lib\Tools\News.php on line 93

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile() [domdocument.loadhtmlfile]: Opening and ending tag mismatch: font and b in http://dizli.com/dizli/db.html, line: 106 in C:\development\app_server\C7\Lib\Tools\News.php on line 93

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile() [domdocument.loadhtmlfile]: htmlParseEntityRef: no name in http://dizli.com/dizli/db.html, line: 115 in C:\development\app_server\C7\Lib\Tools\News.php on line 93

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile() [domdocument.loadhtmlfile]: Opening and ending tag mismatch: td and b in http://dizli.com/dizli/db.html, line: 126 in C:\development\app_server\C7\Lib\Tools\News.php on line 93

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile() [domdocument.loadhtmlfile]: Opening and ending tag mismatch: td and font in http://dizli.com/dizli/db.html, line: 126 in C:\development\app_server\C7\Lib\Tools\News.php on line 93

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile() [domdocument.loadhtmlfile]: Opening and ending tag mismatch: font and b in http://dizli.com/dizli/db.html, line: 128 in C:\development\app_server\C7\Lib\Tools\News.php on line 93

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile() [domdocument.loadhtmlfile]: htmlParseEntityRef: no name in http://dizli.com/dizli/db.html, line: 1575 in C:\development\app_server\C7\Lib\Tools\News.php on line 93

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile() [domdocument.loadhtmlfile]: Tag blink invalid in http://dizli.com/dizli/db.html, line: 2190 in C:\development\app_server\C7\Lib\Tools\News.php on line 93

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile() [domdocument.loadhtmlfile]: Opening and ending tag mismatch: td and b in http://dizli.com/dizli/db.html, line: 2200 in C:\development\app_server\C7\Lib\Tools\News.php on line 93

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile() [domdocument.loadhtmlfile]: Opening and ending tag mismatch: td and font in http://dizli.com/dizli/db.html, line: 2200 in C:\development\app_server\C7\Lib\Tools\News.php on line 93

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile() [domdocument.loadhtmlfile]: Opening and ending tag mismatch: body and center in http://dizli.com/dizli/db.html, line: 2225 in C:\development\app_server\C7\Lib\Tools\News.php on line 93

Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMNodeList could not be converted to string in C:\development\app_server\C7\Lib\Tools\News.php on line 102
```

Can someone help me parse this link, so that I can save the Movie's names and Director's name.

Thanks in advance. 
Zeeshan

Comment: Somewhat related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148928/disable-warnings-when-loading-non-well-formed-html-by-domdocument-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page is written in very old HTML code (you can tell by the FONT tags, capitalization, etc.) and so <br> tags and probably paragraphs and other things as well, are not closed. I recommend using regular expressions to find them in this case.

Answer (score 5):

To hide the errors and still work with that code, just ad `@` before `$dom`, like:

```
$html = @$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
```

Comment: Why does this work? What is the `@` operator? could you explain please?

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is the last line:

```
echo $movie;
```

`$movie` is an instance of [`DOMNodeList`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) so you can´t just echo it, you need to get it´s elements like for example `$movie->item(0)`

You can also just do a `var_dump` of `$movie` and see what that gets you.

The warnings you can possibly ignore, that depends on the output you get.