# PHP Regext to select hidden fields name , value

Tags: php, regex

How to right php regex to extract hidden fiedls name , value pair from html ?

Comment: You don't regex HTML - you parse it.

Comment: but this code don't work as html is mailformed 
function getHidden($formAsString) {  
 $hidEles="";  
 $doc=new DOMDocument();  
 $doc->loadHTML($formAsString);  
 $xpath=new DOMXPath($doc);  
 $query="//input[@type='hidden']";  
 $hidData=$xpath->query($query);  
 foreach($hidData as $field) {  
  //type cast the value to string  
  $name=(string) $field->getAttribute('name');  
  $value=(string) $field->getAttribute('value');  
  $hidEles[$name]=$value;  
 }  
 return $hidEles;  
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per usual, DO NOT USE REGEX TO PROCESS HTML

Use dom:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML('your html here');

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$hidden = $xp->query("//input[@type='hidden']");
for ($i = 0; $i < $hidden->length; $i++) {
    echo $hidden[$i]->getAttribute('name');
}
```

EDIT: Just saw your comment about the malformed html: Use [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) to clean up the HTML. Hopefully it's not so mangled that Purifier can't clean it up to a state that DOM will accept it.

Comment: hi I already have same type of code but I am getting lot of error like  Warning: DOMDocument:: loadHTML () [ domdocument.loadhtml ]: Unexpected end tag: a in Entity, line: 660 in C: \ wamp \ www \ curl2.php on line 8
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0006 706192 {Main} () .. \ Curl2.php : 0
2 12.0399 814832 getHidden () .. \ Curl2.php : 41
3 12.0400 815640 DOMDocument-> loadHTML ()

Comment: It would be nice to have a `DO NOT USE REGEX TO PROCESS HTML` button. All it would do would be to paste that phrase.

Comment: @cwallenpoole: automatically closing any question that has "regex" and "htmL" in the text would be nice.

Comment: @Mar B how to disable dom warning ?

Comment: With 40k rep, can't you more-or-less do things like that? You're double the magical number

Comment: @cwallenpoole: Nope, I can't auto-close, only vote to close. Not sure what the required rep is for insta-close.

Comment: @Vidya: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148928/disable-warnings-when-loading-non-well-formed-html-by-domdocument-php

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you actually have invalid HTML, DomDocument is not able to parse. You can go around that by repairing it first, for example with the [Tidy PHP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php), it's very easy:

```
$html = 'you HTML here';
$html = tidy_repair_string($html);
```

Then [proceed as Marc B suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848225/php-regext-to-select-hidden-fields-name-value/6848264#6848264).