# DOMDocument on loadHTML some tags dissapear

Tags: php

I'am getting all the content of the page, but after `$dom->loadHTML($data)`:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: input conversion failed due to input error, bytes 0x98 0xD0 0xBD 0xD0 in test.php on line 10
```

How to ignore malformed html to not remove it? because I miss some neccesary tags

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17559716/1438393) answer helps.

Comment: PHP DOM is **VERY** picky about malformed html. you'd be better off fixing the html instead of trying to break DOM.

Comment: but I'am parsing it from other site, and there the html is invalid, but I need these tags, no the libxml didn't helped with this

Comment: Try Tidy (http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.tidy.php) or maybe sax the parser.

Comment: my hosting doesn't support tidy

Comment: You could try the PECL pacage http://pecl.php.net/package/tidy