# Get OuterHtml from another website with php

Tags: php, outerhtml

I feed my website with info coming from a table in another website. I used to get the needed info with:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.example.ex');
```

and then work with it through regular expressions.

Unfortunately, the other website has changed, and now the source code is not an HTML table anymore.

But, if I Inspect the element with the info (Chrome browser) I find out it is a table, and I can "copy" the "Outer-HTML" of that element and "paste" it into my files.

Is there any other way, more "professional", to capture that info (the Outer-HTML of an element or the whole page), than copy-paste? Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Give an example of what the content looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this post is useful to you : [Stackoverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446598/get-div-content-from-external-website)

But if this doesn't work. Someone over there suggests a PHP web scraper Framework called [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte) which could be (more) useful to you if the website changes again.