# How to get div values from another website in PHP

Tags: php

How to get div  values from another website in PHP? Is there a way?

Comment: look at this question, it's related to what you ask. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446598/get-div-content-from-external-website (possible duplicate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really simple its called **WEB SCRAPING** you can do this using `regex` regular expression and there is also a library called `simple html dom` using this you can do what you wanted pretty easily :)

Here is the reference manual [Reference](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

This
`$ret = $html->find('div[class=classname]');` 
can get what you want!
or
`$ret = $html->find('.div'sclassname')`

Comment: hey @Mohammad if the answer solved your querie please give a green resolved tick on my answer ! happy to help :)