# Get DIV content by specific string

Tags: php

I like the solution from [Get DIV content from external Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446598/get-div-content-from-external-website), but I need to find the value from a DIV class which contains a specific string, like in my case **btx764839** (for example). The name of the div class is not that string alone but `<div class="dark btx764839">76</div>` for example.

I need the script to search for the DIV that contains **btx764839** and then refer to that specific one. I've been trying many different things with `strpos();`, without success. Below the script I found on the other post (without my adjustments). I would appreciate some help. Thank you very much!

```
$url = 'url';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$first_step = explode( '<div class="dark btx764839">' , $content );
$second_step = explode("</div>" , $first_step[1] );

echo $second_step[0];
```

This is my latest attempt:

```
$url = 'url';
$content = file_get_contents($url);

foreach($content as $div) {
    // Loop through the DIVs looking for one withan id of "content"
    // Then echo out its contents (pardon the pun)

    // get class attribute of a div, it's a string
    $class = $div->getAttribute('class');

    // find substring 'btx764839' in $class
    if (strpos($class, 'btx764839') !== false) {
         echo $div->nodeValue;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code taken from provided example:

```
foreach($divs as $div) {
    // Loop through the DIVs looking for one withan id of "content"
    // Then echo out its contents (pardon the pun)

    // get class attribute of a div, it's a string
    $class = $div->getAttribute('class');

    // find substring 'btx764839' in $class
    if (strpos($class, 'btx764839') !== false) {
         echo $div->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how to combine your code with mine. The code refers to the content of another page `$url = 'url';`.