# php get all div content from external website

Tags: php

I want to get all div content of the site

I want to get this div

```
<div class="user_name"/>
```

there are so many user_name as class name of the divs in the page but I want to get all div content

I have this code which I got it here [Get DIV content from external Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446598/get-div-content-from-external-website)

```
$url = 'http://www.myexternalsite.com/user/1';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$first_step = explode( '<div class="user_name"/>' , $content );
$second_step = explode("</div>" , $first_step[1] );

echo $second_step[0];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get DIV content from external Website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446598/get-div-content-from-external-website)

Comment: yes but I want to get all the divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try 
[PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)