# domDocument is not returning node information

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I'm attempting to get the DOM elements of external pages. Based on other posts I'm trying:

```
$html = htmlentities(file_get_contents('http://www.slate.com'));    
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($dom);
echo "</pre>";
```

(Html entites kills warnings, but otherwise has the same result as leaving it out).

Based on what I've read, this should return various DOM parts in parent/child nodes.  But the result of the code above contains no DOM nodes, just a huge "textContent" element that contains the entire page HTML.

Thanks in advance for thoughts on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: If you want to sisable warnings use `libxml_use_internal_errors(true)` . You cann't load DomDocument after `htmlentities`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for

```
$dom->documentElement
```

this will return a

```
DOMNode
```

object.

Also: Get rid of the `htmlentities` because this will mess up the HTML code you fetch. e.g.: `<` will get `&lt`, which your `loadHTML` won't interpret as a `<`. Take a look at: [Disable warnings when loading non-well-formed HTML by DomDocument (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148928/disable-warnings-when-loading-non-well-formed-html-by-domdocument-php)

Dummy-Dump:

```
function dump(DOMNode $node)
{
    echo $node->nodeName;
    if ($node->hasChildNodes())
    {
        echo '<div style="margin-left:20px; border-left:1px solid black; padding-left: 5px;">';
        foreach ($node->childNodes as $childNode)
        {
            dump($childNode);
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
}

dump($dom->documentElement);
```

Which looks like:

[image: Dummy-Dump]

Comment: Got me where I needed to go.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using phpQuery (https://github.com/electrolinux/phpquery).

Comment: Seems like shooting cannons on sparrows since we don't know what @daprezjer is up to...