# PHP DOMDocument loading custom tags

Tags: php, html

PHP's DOMDocument can create and insert arbitrary tags.

```
$doc=new DOMDocment();
$doc->loadHTML($basic_html);
$foo=$doc->createElement('foo');
$doc->getElementById('body')->appendChild($foo);
echo $doc->saveHTML()
//OUPUTS
<html><body id='body'><foo></foo></body></html>
```

But if I load that HTML with ->loadHTML() it drops any tags it doesn't recognize. Can I not load without validation? Why can I create arbitrarily named tags but not import them?

Comment: here's the answer, add this, tested it before commenting http://stackoverflow.com/a/17559716/3859027